# Amazom Redshift View deleted automatically

Tags: view, amazon-redshift

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW viewname AS select from 
 tablename;
```

I have created a View in database i is automatically deleted some time interval.
Tried many times same issue occured.
any possibilities to resolve this issue?

Advance thanks

Comment: looks like something is deleting the upstream table, check if you do deep copies or something like this

Comment: are you commiting after creating the view?

Comment: No  jon, just create the view only.

Comment: I have tried with commit but no luck same issue continue.-